# Probabity for raining in at least $3$ days

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> A building contractor knows that the probability of rain in his region
>   during any given day in August is $30\%$. He has $2$ days work remaining on
>   the job and there are $4$ days during which the work can be done without
>   incurring penalty costs. If he gets no work done on rainy days, what
>   is the probability that he will pay penalty? Assume that rain on any
>   given day is independent of the fact that it did or did not rain on
>   any other day.

I got two different answers and posting it here for understanding the right approach and right answer. Please tell me which is the right answer from the following. Thanks.

---

### **Answer 1**

Source:  [José Rizal University  MPA Program Reported by Group I](http://b1.rimg.tw/kochente/9a40d391.ppt) (slide no.$37$)

[image]

---

### **Answer 2**

Source: [careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3380#top)

[image]

Comment: The first method is wrong.  In the exactly three rainy day scenario you only count the case in which the first three days are rainy and the fourth is good.  You need to multiply that term by $4$ to cover the fact that the good day could be any of the $4$.  Note:  if you do that then you get $.3^4+4\times .3^3 \times .7 = .0837$, consistent with your second method.

Comment: @lulu, thanks a lot for the help.